# Possible to Use jQuery JSON For Multiple HTML Pages?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, get

I have an HTML page where the user fills in a few forms for their own reference (purely client-side, it doesn't get submitted to server). I'd like to be able to store that submitted text on the user's computer, and then reproduce that text on another HTML page when the user visits the other page.

Is this possible to do using jQuery JSON? Perhaps with .getJSON and/or .parseJSON? (If so, I would guess that both HTML pages need to refer to the same .JS file.)

Or would this be more of a cookie thing?

Also, if this is possible, I would love a link to an article about how to do this - if one exists.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: findout about localstorage.

Comment: Seconding @Jai, that's the [localstorage](http://mdn.io/localstorage) use case…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sort of browser support you need, but [eligrey/FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) will save your file, but javascript can't automatically read content from a user's computer without their input - [this is a tutorial on reading files submitted by the user](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

If you want this to be seamless, you want to use [cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/autosave/) or [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Answer (score -1):

As all variables are lost when the javascript is reloaded (which happens when the user loads another HTML which references the same .js), you could store the values in a browser Cookie.

You can serialize the data as JSON in the cookie if you'd like, this is entirely up to you.